# Расширение базового интерфейса класса в потомке

Tags: c++, проектирование

Доброго времени суток!

Возник вопрос при проектировании классов контролёров для представлений. 
К примеру, есть следующая иерархия классов:

```
class IController 
{
public:
    virtual void add(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual void edit(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual ~IController() = default; 
};

class StandartController : public IController
{
public:
    virtual void add(/*...*/) override;
    virtual void edit(/*...*/) override;
}
```

Нужно также предусмотреть расширенную версию контролёра:

```
class ExtentedController : public IController
{
public:
    virtual void add(/*...*/) override;
    virtual void edit(/*...*/) override;
    virtual void find(/*...*/);
    virtual void sort(/*...*/);
    // ... и другие методы
}
```

Как теперь при наличии расширенного потомка единообразно использовать интерфейс? Думал применить решение с dynamic_cast, но мне кажется, что в данном случае его применение будет свидетельствовать о наличии каких-либо проблем с архитектурой. Второй вариант был выделить расширенный класс в совершенно новую иерархию. Но имеет ли это смысл? Скорее всего есть более удачные решения. Прошу помощи :-)

Дополнительно к основному вопросу:
Для производства контролёров используется фабрика, которая возвращает только указатель на интерфейс (IController*) в независимости от того, какой тип объекта потребовался клиенту. Сигнатура принимающего метода представления выглядит следующим образом: `void setController(IContoller* ctrl)`. 
Представления, по сути, являются тоже некой иерархией классов (Один интерфейс - множество реализаций).

```
class IView
{
public:
   IView() = delete;
   IView(/*...*/);
   ~IView() = default;
   //...
   void setController(IContoller* ctrl);
   //... другие методы
};
```

При проектировании использовался принцип "программирования на уровне интерфейсов", но когда стали появляться реализации "не такие как все", возникли проблемы с их использованием. Ведь все представление знают только об интерфейсе контролёра. Можно, конечно, в представлении сделать каст к нужному типу, но повторюсь, меня так смущает эта операция, что я всё же ищу другое решение.

Comment: А в чем проблема? `find` и `sort` появляются только в расширенном контроллере, так что и использоваться они могут только там, где ожидается расширенный контроллер. Вы не должны использовать их там, где ожидается "контроллер вообще"... Т.е. я, откровенно говоря, вообще никакой проблемы не вижу пока что.

Comment: Я вижу только одну проблему - если пишете override у функции, то virtual уже излишне. Нормальные компиляторы даже ругаются.

Comment: @Harry, например, если фабрика контролёров возвращает указатель на интерфейс, а сигнатура принимающего метода выглядит так: `void setController(IContoller* ctrl);` . В данном случае внутри принимающего метода придётся применить dynamic_cast. Читал, что использовать dynamic_cast нужно аккуратно и там где ему место. Поэтому возникли сомнения в его использовании здесь. Что если потребуется ещё добавить ещё 2 или 3 расширенных контроллеров? В место использования добавиться 2, 3 dynamic_cast?

Comment: @Steven, у вас классы с методом `void setController(IContoller* ctrl);` могут на самом деле принимать любой контроллер? Или все таки некоторые из них ожидают именно `ExtentedController`?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, могут принимать любой контролёр, который реализует интерфейс IContoller.

Comment: @Steven, а при каких обстоятельствах нужны методы `ExtentedController`? Все ведь и так могут работать с `IContoller`

Comment: @Steven Ну и ладушки - передавайте в `void setController(IContoller* ctrl);` указатель на расширенный контроллер. Ведь внутри - раз передается указатель на `IContoller` - методы `find` и `sort` использоваться не могут, правда? Если принимающему методу нужны эти вызовы - то он и принимать должен указатель на `ExtendedController`, логично?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, если представление используется для поиска информации. К примеру, программа позволяет вести несколько простых справочников (ID, ПОЛЕ). Реакцию представления справочников обрабатывает StandartController.  На основании простых справочников строится регистр, который помимо сохранения и редактирования регистровой записи (основные функции контролёра), позволяет искать информацию по справочникам или производить фильтрацию полученных данных (на представлении есть несколько дополнительных кнопок).

Comment: @Harry, совершенно верно, это логично, но фабрика, которая произвела этот контролёр, возвращает указатель на интерфейс. Фабрика всегда возвращает указатель на интерфейс -  ей всё равно какой тип у контроллера. Восходящие приведение разве разрешено? IController -> ExtentedController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу ничего страшного в dynamic_cast, только не к расширенному классу - а к отдельному интерфейсу. То есть для каждого нового расширения делается свой инетерфейс, и расширенный класс наследуется от нескольки интерфейсов. Тот кто хочет воспользоваться расширенным функционалом объекта - пытается скастить его к интересующему интерфейсу - получилось, использует.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <memory>

class IController 
{
public:
    virtual void add(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual void edit(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual ~IController() = default; 
};

class StandartController : public IController
{
public:
    virtual void add(/*...*/) override;
    virtual void edit(/*...*/) override;
};

class IControllerSearch
{
public:
    virtual void find(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual void sort(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual ~IControllerSearch() = default; 

};

class ExtentedController : public IController, public IControllerSearch
{
public:
    void add(/*...*/) override{};
    void edit(/*...*/) override{};
    void find(/*...*/) override{};
    void sort(/*...*/) override{};
    // ... и другие методы
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IController>> v;

    v.push_back(std::shared_ptr<IController>(new ExtentedController));

    for(auto& c:v){
        std::shared_ptr<IControllerSearch> cs = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IControllerSearch>(c);
        if(cs){
            cs->find();
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```